# Prove that $\dfrac{b^{n-1}a(a+b)(a+2b)\cdots(a+(n-1)b)}{n!}$ is an integer

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $a$ and $b$ be integers and $n$ a positive integer. Prove that $$\dfrac{b^{n-1}a(a+b)(a+2b)\cdots(a+(n-1)b)}{n!}$$ is an integer.

Define $v_p(x)$ such that if $v_p(x) = n$, then $p^n \mid x$ but $p^{n+1} \nmid x$. Then we need to show that $v_p(b^{n-1})+v_p(a)+v_p(a+b)+\cdots+v_p(a+(n-1)b)\geq v_p(n!)$ for all primes $p$. How should we do that?

Comment: The terms need not form a complete residue system modulo $n$. They do if $b$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: The problem is general enough!  I have no immediate plan of attack. There are many proofs of the special case $b=1$.  Possibly one of them can be adapted.

Comment: One approach is to show that if $p$ is a prime that does not divide $b$, then the terms $a, \dots, a+(n-1)p$ have "enough" $p$'s. For the other primes, the $b^{n-1}$ should be enough to push us over.

Answer (score 2):

Fix a prime natural number $p$.  For an integer $m$ and a nonnegative integer $r$, let $p^r\parallel m$ denote the condition that $p^r\mid m$ but $p^{r+1}\nmid m$.  We shall ignore the trivial cases (namely, $n=1$, $a=0$, and $b=0$).  Suppose that $p^k\parallel a$ and $p^l\parallel b$ for some integers $k,l\geq 0$.

First, we assume that $k <  l$ (whence $l\geq 1$).  It follows immediately that $v_p(a+jb)=v_p(a)=k$ for all $j=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$.  Thus, $$v_p\left(b^{n-1}\,\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\,(a+jb)\right)=v_p\left(b^{n-1}\right)+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\,v_p(a+jb)=(n-1)l+nk\,.$$  Note that $$v_p(n!)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\,\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^j}\right\rfloor<\sum_{j=1}^\infty\,\frac{n}{p^j}\leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty\,\frac{n}{2^j}=n\,.$$
Consequently, $\displaystyle v_p(n!)\leq n-1\leq (n-1)l\leq (n-1)l+nk=v_p\left(b^{n-1}\,\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\,(a+jb)\right)$.

Now, suppose that $k \geq l$.  Then, it is evident that, for every $s=1,2,\ldots$, the congruence $$a+jb\equiv 0\,\pmod{p^{l+s}}$$ has at least $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^s}\right\rfloor$ solutions $j\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.  That is,
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\,v_p(a+jb)\geq nl+\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\,\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^s}\right\rfloor=nl+v_p(n!)\geq v_p(n!)\,.$$
Ergo, we again obtain $\displaystyle v_p(n!)\leq v_p\left(b^{n-1}\,\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\,(a+jb)\right)$.

That is, in all cases, $\displaystyle v_p(n!)\leq v_p\left(b^{n-1}\,\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\,(a+jb)\right)$.  Because $p$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $n!$ divides $\displaystyle b^{n-1}\,\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\,(a+jb)$.  I believe that there should be a combinatorial proof of this statement, and hope to see it.

Comment: How does it follow that $v_p(a+jb) = v_p(a) = k$?

Comment: What is $\gcd\left(\frac{a+jb}{p^k},p\right)$?

Comment: About the congruence you said having that many solutions, what if we had like $125+j \cdot 625 = 5^3(1+5j)$. Where are the solutions for $j$ here?

Comment: I'm assuming you are taking $p=5$, $a=125$, and $b=625$.  What are $k$ and $l$ in this case?  Do they satisfy $k\geq l$?

Comment: You may switch it to $p = 5, a = 625,$ and $b= 125$. Then we have $5^3(j+5)$.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Which $s$ do you want?  Which $n$ do you want?

Comment: I see now. You are right. Also, why did you say we can ignore the trivial cases if they don't matter?

Comment: Why not?  Just to be thorough.  In fact, the case $a=0$ or $b=0$ breaks my proof, as $k$ or $l$ doesn't exist.

Comment: How should we define $0^0$?

Comment: In a formulation like this, $0^0$ is usually taken to be $1$, since we treat the whole expression as a polynomial in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Why do you add $nl$ in $nl+\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^s}\right\rfloor$?

Comment: Because each $a+bj$ already has a factor $p^l$.